# What is direct to board solderable ribbon cable called?

Tags: ribbon-cable

Some products I've seen attach PCBs with a solder-able type of ribbon cable on a 0.1" pitch.  What is this called?  Is there an example at Digikey?

This ribbon cable is used for direct board to board (no connectors) and is soldered into a single inline pin pattern on 0.1" pitch.  It also needs to be high temperature since it is soldered, not the PVC of 'typical' ribbon cable that melts.

TIA[image]

Comment: Its definitely 0.1" pitch and you can solder it directly into the holes for a single inline pin pattern.  The photo was from https://shop.pedalparts.co.uk/DirectConnect_prestripped_ribbon_cables_4_6_7_and_9way/p847124_13242332.aspx    - but their term "direct connect ribbon" isn't the standard.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example from digikey (Part no.: 3M156019-100-ND). This is a solid core flat ribbon cable like your picture.

FPC and FFC cable are flex circuit board with traces for the "wires". They're different from what your picture shows.

Comment: When I search digikey for that term I get 25 mil pitch 30 awg.  I'm after something probably around 20 awg on a 0.1" pitch.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like on Digikey it is under the category of :
Flat Flex Ribbon Jumpers, Cables

Here is an example:
https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/FST-22A-5/5399439

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/flat-flex-ribbon-jumpers-cables/457
Then select 0.1" pitch

Newark calls it what I would expect  "Ribbon Cable, Board to Board Jumper"
https://www.newark.com/molex/25001-0802/cable-assy-8pos-50mm/dp/25M1993

Comment: Flat-flex is not what you want.